# Matching a string pattern which starts and ends with a string in imacros

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match, imacros

Suppose This is my text

```
    SET abc "<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlyear" class="page-heading" style="background-color: rgb(255, 244, 244); width: 95px; outline: 1px solid blue;">    <option selected="selected" value="Select Year">Select Year</option>    <option value="2000">2000</option>   
<option value="2001">2001</option>   
<option value="2002">2002</option>  
<option value="2003">2003</option>   
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>    
<option value="2006">2006</option>    
<option value="2007">2007</option>    
<option value="2008">2008</option>    
<option value="2009">2009</option>    
<option value="2010">2010</option>    
<option value="2011">2011</option>    
<option value="2012">2012</option>    
<option value="2013">2013</option>    
<option value="2014">2014</option>    
<option value="2015">2015</option>    
<option value="2016">2016</option>    
<option value="2017">2017</option>    
</select>"
```

And  I just want to extract years from the above text, so I matched the staring string as `<option value=` and ending string as `</option>` and get the string between these two pattern

```
SET text EVAL("var s=\"{{abc}}\"; s.match(\"(?![<option value=])(.*)(?=</option>)\");")
```

But it gives the entire text again
And if I do

```
SET text EVAL("var s=\"{{abc}}\"; s.match(\"(?![<option value=])(.*)(?=</option>)\");s[0]")
```

This gives me `"<"`
Any suggestion where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try a simpler way like this:

```
TAG XPATH="id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlyear')" EXTRACT=TXTALL
SET numbers EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace('Select Year[OPTION]', '');")
PROMPT {{numbers}}
```

Comment: this gives output as "2000[OPTION]2001[OPTION]2002[OPTION]2003[OPTION]2004[OPTION]2005[OPTION]2006[OPTION]2007[OPTION]2008[OPTION]2009[OPTION]2010[OPTION]2011[OPTION]2012[OPTION]2013[OPTION]2014[OPTION]2015[OPTION]2016[OPTION]2017"

Answer (score 0):

I can't test an imacros version, but your plain regex is wrongfully using square brackets and negative lookahead.

Here is a regex that matches what you are looking for (all digits before an `</option>`) :

> ([0-9]*)(?=</option>)

Demo here :
https://regex101.com/r/jA3Al9/2

Edit : as I said I can't test it but I guess you are looking for :

> `SET text EVAL("var s=\"{{abc}}\"; s.match(\"([0-9]*)(?=</option>)\");s[0]")`

Answer (score 0):

From @Shugar's answer added few lines to get the answer

```
TAG XPATH="id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlyear')" EXTRACT=TXTALL
SET numbers EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace('Select Year[OPTION]', '');")
SET numb1 EVAL("'{{numbers}}'.replace(/[OPTION]/g,'');")
SET numb2 EVAL("'{{numb1}}'.split('[]')")
PROMPT {{numb2}}
```

Comment: One line is mostly enough: `SET numbers EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace('Select Year[OPTION]', '').split('[OPTION]');")`